# crystal report loading blank when used with master page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I just created a sample rpt file with just a Header and footer in it. And loaded that report in an aspx page without a master page. That worked fine. But when i add the same report to a page which has a master page, the report is not loading. It is showing just a white blank page.

```
 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
                            AutoDataBind="True" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="50px" 
                            ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl=""  DisplayStatusbar="false" DisplayToolbar="False" ToolPanelView="None" 
                            ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="350px" HasPageNavigationButtons="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" HasDrillUpButton="False" HasGotoPageButton="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false" />
                        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
                            <Report  FileName="../Reports/StatisticDataReport.rpt">
                            </Report>
                        </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

this is what i added in both aspx pages. I Don't have an idea on what is wrong.